# Strategy Pattern - C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm having an issue implementing a strategy pattern to my project. I created all the files necessary, however I am getting an error with my new call in main as I can't seem to initialize a strategy to what I want.

Strategy.h

```
/*All the classes that implement a concrete strategy should use this
The AI class will use this file as a concrete strategy
*/
using namespace std;
class Strategy{
public:
    //Method who's implementation varies depending on the strategy adopted
    //Method is therefore virtual
    virtual int execute() = 0;
 };
```

My three strategies
Aggressive.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Strategy.h"

class Aggressive{
   public:
      int execute();

 };
```

Aggressive.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Strategy.h"
using namespace std;

class Aggressive : public Strategy{
  public:
      Aggressive(){}

      int execute(){
        cout << "The defensive player chooses to adopt an aggressive play-                             style" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

};
```

Defensive.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Strategy.h"

class Defensive{
  public:
     int execute();

};
```

Defensive.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Strategy.h"
using namespace std;

 class Defensive : public Strategy{
    public:
       int execute(){
        cout << "The defensive player chooses to adopt a defensive play-style" << endl;
    }
 };
```

AI.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Strategy.h"

class AI{
  public:
    AI();
    AI(Strategy *initStrategy);
    void setStrategy(Strategy *newStrategy);
    int executeStrategy();

};
```

AI.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Strategy.h"
#include "AI.h"
#include "Aggressive.h"
#include "Defensive.h"


using namespace std;

 class AI{
   private:
       Strategy *strategy;
   public:
      AI(){}
         //Plugs in specific strategy to be adopted
      AI(Strategy *initStrategy){
          this->strategy = initStrategy;
      }
      void setStrategy(Strategy *newStrategy){
          this->strategy = newStrategy;
      }
      //Method that executes a different strategy depending on what 
      //strategt was plugged in upon instantiation.
       int executeStrategy(){
          return this->strategy->execute();
      }
  };
```

And my temporary driver, which has an issue with new
StrategyDriver.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "AI.h"
#include "Strategy.h"
#include "Aggressive.h"
#include "Defensive.h"
#include "Random.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
   AI *ai(new Aggressive());
    ai->executeStrategy();  
}
```

If anyone sees the issue with my code, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not entirely sure on how to initialize the new ai to specific strategies that were implemented.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message pls ?

Comment: My error message is regarding the new in main.  error: a value of type "Aggressive" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "AI"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define the same class twice, once in the header and once in a source file. `main` only sees the definition in the header, which doesn't inherit from `Strategy`, hence the error.

The header needs to define the class, declaring all its parent classes and members:

```
#pragma once
#include "Strategy.h"

class Aggressive : public Strategy{
public:
    Aggressive(){}
    int execute();
};
```

and the source file just defines any members that weren't defined in the header:

```
// no header guard (#pragma once) - that's just for headers
#include <iostream>
#include "Aggressive.h"  // include the class definition
using namespace std;

int Aggressive::execute(){
    cout << "The defensive player chooses to adopt an aggressive play-                             style" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With these changes, the class definition will be available where it's used in `main`, so the conversion from `Aggressive*` to a base-class pointer `Strategy*` will be allowed. You'll need to make similar changes to the other classes for the program to build and run correctly.

Finally, `main` wants to create an `AI` object (which can be initialised with a `Strategy*`) not an `AI*` pointer (which can't).

```
AI ai(new Aggressive());
ai.executeStrategy();
```

Comment: Despite changing the header and source file as you said, I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: @VincentFugnitto: Oh yes, you're trying to initialise a pointer to `AI` rather than an object. I didn't spot that.

Comment: yes the error I'm receiving, while not being a compilation error, just an error under the word new is : error: a value of type "Aggressive* " cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "AI* "

Comment: @VincentFugnitto: See the update. You want an `AI` object, not a pointer.

Comment: I did the change, AI ai(new Aggressive()); ai.executeStrategy(); and I'm not receiving the error. Is that the appropriate change to resolve the issue?

Comment: @VincentFugnitto: That should at least compile and call the right function. If it doesn't, and you can't figure out what's wrong, you should probably reduce the code to a simple [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post another question.

Comment: Mike I've gotten a lot of compiler errors for my code, I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: @VincentFugnitto: If you can't figure out what's wrong, you should probably reduce the code to a simple [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Christophe's answer, You are defining your **.cpp** file wrong. The general design approach is that

1. You should only have to include the relevant **.h** in the corresponding **.cpp** unless you want to include implementation specific headers.
2. You define the methods in the **.cpp** file, not the class itself unless you don't have a corresponding **.h** file. More reading on this came be done here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/
3. It is considered bad practice to have **using namespace x** in your **.cpp** files. If you want to include a namespace like that, do it in your header file.

There is probably more things wrong, but you will get rid of a lot of the dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your strategy `Agressive` does not derive from `Strategy`. So you know that `Agressive` **is a** `Strategy` but your compiler don't.

The strong type checking rules prevent therefore the compiler from converting blindly pointers between apparently unrelated types, here:

```
AI *ai(new Aggressive());
```

The solution is to adapt your strategies by making them inheriting publicly from from `Strategy`:

```
class Aggressive : public Strategy {
public:
    int execute();

};
```

Of course, you should do the same for the other strategies as well.  Your code then compiles without further problems.

Comment: I did the changes your proposed by doing the : public Strategy for each .h and .cpp file for every strategy but I still get the same error on my new in the main.  I have the error, error: a value of type "Aggressive" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "AI"